# How to solve runtime exception of jdom library?

Tags: java, jdom

I want to make a kml file from a java code using `jdom-1.1.jar` library file. It gives no compile time error to my program but showing a run time error:

```
C:\ProgramFiles\Tomcat\tomcat-5.5.9\webapps\jsp-examples>java KmlSample
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdom/Content
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdom.Content
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: KmlSample.  Program will exit.
```

how can i resolve such error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitily have to tell Java where to find the jdom library (and other libraries you may need). Assuming you have the library in some folder `/dev/lib`, then the correct command would be like this:

```
java -cp .;/dev/lib/jdom-1.1.jar KmlSample
```

This command further assumes that the file `KmlSample.class` is at the current location *and* that the class `KmlSample` is defined in the default namespace (`KmlSample.java` does not have a `package` statement) *and* the `KmlClass` has a correct `main` method (entry point).

---

**Edit**

```
$> cd C:\programfiles\tomcat\tomcat-5.5.9\webapps\jsp-examples
$> java -cp .;../../common/lib/jdom-1.1.jar KmlSample
```

This should work (or at least it should produce a different error message)

---

Make sure, the *current directory* (from where you execute java in the above example) contains the file `KmlSample.class` (have a look at the upper section of my answer). You mentioned a `KmlSample.java` file at that location - have you compiled the source?

Comment: The dir structure for my java and class file is: C:\programfiles\tomcat\tomcat-5.5.9\webapps\jsp-examples\KmlSample.java and path to my jdom is : "c:\programfiles\tomcat\tomcat-5.5.9\common\lib\jdom-1.1.jar. I hav tried -cp option with java command but its not working and gave the same error message..

Comment: it is now showing error message "NoClassDefFoundError: KmlSample" instead of "NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdom/Content"

Answer (score 1):

you need to add jdom-1.1.jar on your classpath, so show how you are running your program, should be like

```
java -classpath /path/to/jdom-1.1.jar;. YourMainClassFile
```

Comment: i hav tried ur option also but it doesn't work and gave same error msg.

Comment: C:\ProgramFiles\Tomcat\tomcat-5.5.9\webapps\jsp-examples>java -cp c:\programfile
s\tomcat\tomcat-5.5.9\lib\jdom-1.1.jar KmlSample
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: KmlSample
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: KmlSample
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: items on the classpath need to be separated by semicolons(;) in windows, or colons(:) on linux, not spaces as you have.

Comment: i didnt use any spaces in -cp option. sorry for the mistake in the previous comment... But it is now showing error message dat "NoClassDefFoundError: KmlSample" nt "NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdom/Content".